# Compile error "already defined"

Tags: c++

It looks like this:

```
error LNK2005: "unsigned long __cdecl GetModuleBase(void *,
class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,
class std::allocator<char> > &)" 
(?GetModuleBase@@YAKPAXAAV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) 
already defined
```

And code i have recently added:

```
#include "Windows.h"
#include <TlHelp32.h>
#include <psapi.h>
#include <string>
#pragma comment(lib, "psapi")
//#pragma comment(lib, "TlHelp32") i could not find where this lib located
using namespace std;

DWORD GetModuleBase(HANDLE hProc, string &sModuleName) 
{ 
   HMODULE *hModules; 
   char szBuf[50]; 
   DWORD cModules; 
   DWORD dwBase = -1; 
   //------ 

   EnumProcessModules(hProc, hModules, 0, &cModules); 
   hModules = new HMODULE[cModules/sizeof(HMODULE)]; 

   if(EnumProcessModules(hProc, hModules, cModules/sizeof(HMODULE), &cModules)) { 
      for(int i = 0; i < cModules/sizeof(HMODULE); i++) { 
         if(GetModuleBaseName(hProc, hModules[i], szBuf, sizeof(szBuf))) { 
            if(sModuleName.compare(szBuf) == 0) { 
               dwBase = (DWORD)hModules[i]; 
               break; 
            } 
         } 
      } 
   } 

   delete[] hModules; 

   return dwBase; 
}
```

I dont understand what is this, maybe i am using wrong code?
Or TlHelp32.lib is needed, but VS says it cannot find such static library.

Comment: Are your headers guarded with `#ifndef` macro?

Comment: of course not pragma.

Comment: That's a link error, not a compiler error. It suggests that you have two functions called `GetModuleBase` with the same signature. Perhaps you are linking the same code twice?

Comment: GetModuleBase function is defined more than once in the project. Maybe it is defined in two different .cpp files, or in h-file which is included to different .cpp files.

Answer (score 4):

There is a [`GetModuleBase` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155851.aspx) in the namespace `Microsoft::WRL`.

Your code includes the Microsoft's function (in another part of the project, it's internal), so during link phase it raises an error.

Change the name of the function or use a namespace.

Comment: I wondered about this but in a C++ program it should be possible to have two different functions with the same name as long as the signatures are different.

Comment: Thanks, but i've solved my problem (i am sorry) it was include error (i put the function code to header without declaration, probably this was the problem).

Comment: @john: you're right, but as the error says, there is something wrong during the link phase (C++ compiler says all ok). Then as Loryan55 has explained, the declaration was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Your GetModuleBase() function is defined twice and the linker is having trouble resolving the conflict.  Do a search for "GetModuleBase" and you will find it.

Ideally you will declare the function prototype once in a header like so:

```
DWORD GetModuleBase(HANDLE hProc, string &sModuleName);
```

Use header guards or at least this preprocessor directive at the top of your header file:

```
#pragma once
```

Then define GetModuleBase() once in a .cpp file, in this .cpp file you need to include the header file.  Remove any additional declarations or definitions for this function and your problem should be solved.

Anytime you have this problem the fast solution is to CTRL-F to open the find prompt and search for the function name, you will quickly identify the conflict with this method.